# Performance of svg:svg vs svg:g elements

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I'm rewriting a chart and am thinking about switching from wrapping descendant elements in `<g>` elements to `<svg>`. The issue I have is that for what I'm trying to do in every way `<svg>` elements make that easier. What I'm concerned with is will there be any performance impact. `<g>` seems very lightweight, where `<svg>` has more features because it is not so light weight.

So practically is there a penalty?

Comment: You'll have to try in your particular case.

Comment: What are you basing your light weight/not so light weight assertion on?

Comment: @RobertLongson a guess... and what attributes and rules that apply to decedent elements. One example is that <svg> will create a new viewport.

Comment: Better test than guess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the results I have from jsperf is that appending svg is slower than g elements.
http://jsperf.com/svg-vs-g
30% slower in fact, that is if my test is correctly written...

Working on getting the improving them and getting one for translations. I will update my answer when I do.

Comment: That really just proves that percentage units are slow. You've twice as many in the svg test and they need to resolve against the viewport size.

Comment: Just don't use percentages, use px or some other unit instead.

Comment: O. Can you explain more about the costs of rendering or provide a link about it? In my case i'm looking to use percents, and that why im replacing <g> with <svg>, so that I don't have to run any script to update the elements on a page resize.

Comment: I thought I did explain in my first comment. Percentages need to resolve against the viewport size so you need to go up the hierarchy to calculate what the value is.

Comment: If I wanted to read more about how rendering works, is that in the spec? Also, I think your the best person to look at this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772977/

Comment: No, the spec is about what, not how.