# How to find the size of an SVG element across browsers

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to get the size of an element inside of a viewport. For this I have used `getClientBoundingRect()` because it will give me the size after transforms have been applied. The issue I have ran into is that the client rect will not size bigger than the highest viewport. So I switched to `getBBox()`. Now the problem is that it does not work in Firefox. What is the best way to get the size of an element across all the browsers?

[Demo on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/eWeVOfa/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: This is a bug in Firefox, I've tried to fix it but not been successful yet. There's no workaround that I know.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to wrap a div around it:

<kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsbin.com/ahECeRO/1/edit?html,js,console,output)</kbd>

Comment: In the bin, look at the console output for Firefox. One of the log statements should show that the inside content is larger than the viewport. In Chrome and IE the second log statement is correct at "1.5"